# Mercurial how to create patch for added new branch?

Tags: mercurial, patch

I cloned local copy of repo.
I added branch and want to create patch in order to distribute my changes to other developer.

What I did:
1. in local repo merged my branch with the default branch
2. resolved conflicts
3. ran build and checked that everything is ok
4. created patch using: `hg export --git -r tip > build.patch`
5. cloned remote repo via: `hg clone http://`... in order to check
that created patch can be applied correctly

On step 5 I got several messages,
that say hunks FAILED and that .rej files will be generated.
I browsed directories where those files are located and found what there are no files there from my local repo, so after I applied patch files from the branch that I have created haven't been transfered.

How to cope with this problem?

Comment: If your last commit was a merge commit, you might have created the diff / patch against the wrong parent. Create your patch diff by using `hg diff -rUNMODIFIED > file.diff` and try that as patch (UNMODIFIED is the underlaying base revision of the unchanged repo which you created your patch against, thus the last unmodified revision in the default branch.

Comment: @planetmaker - this *is answer*, not comment

Answer (score 1):

1. As @planetmaker noted - don't create patch from mergeset, create it from changeset(s) in branch
2. More hg-ish way will be storing full branch's content in bundle-file (`hg help bundle`, note `-b` option
3. Strictly Mercurial way (unrelated to your habits): store WIP in [MQ](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/MqExtension) queue, share your work with [MQCollab extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/MqCollabExtension)